# Shell script for rename the file - Shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am totally new in shell scripting, but i need to write a shell script which will check if file exist then move to another location

Here what i have written :

Once the device gets crash i am collecting the logs in /storage/sdcard1/1

#!/system/bin/sh

```
if [ -d /storage/sdcard1/1 ]; then
mkdir crash1
mv 1 crash1
fi
```

whever we find /storage/sdcard1/1 dir we have to rename it `crash1,crash2,crash3` respectively.

Which i am not able to understand the logic. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Your question is a nonsense. Please reformulate.

Comment: The question could be clearer!  Do you wish to move the contents of /storage/sdcard1/1 , /storage/sdcard1/2,/storage/sdcard1/3 to crash1, crash2 and crash3?

Comment: `#!/system/bin/sh` also looks like nonsense.  The standard path is `#!/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
target=/home/john/data
if [ -d /storage/sdcard1/1 ]; then
    mv /storage/sdcard1/1 $target/crash1
fi
```

Set the target to the place you wish to make "crash1"
Repeat the code with 2 and 3 in place of 1

Most people would use a variable and loop to do 1,2,3 but let's keep it simple